# Create own bot on telegram with php

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I saw a couple of days ago [this tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJBYojK7DO4).
It was very interesting, so I decided to make a own bot.
I used the code from the tutorial as a template:

```
<?php

$bottoken = "*****";
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$bottoken;


$update = file_get_contents('php://input');

$updatearray = json_decode($update, TRUE);

$length = count($updatearray["result"]);
$chatid = $updatearray["result"][$length-1]["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$text = $updatearray["result"][$length-1]["message"]["text"];

if($text == 'hy'){
    file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatid."&text=hello");
} 
elseif($text == 'ciao'){
    file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatid."&text=bye");
}
```

The script worked if I execute the script manually. However when I use the webhook it doesn't work anymore. The tutorial said that `$update = file_get_contents('php://input');` is the right way, to be used before `$update = file_get_contents($website."/getupdates");`. My question how can I use `php://input` to execute my script automatically? The script is on a server from "one.com" and the certificate is also from "one.com".

Comment: Just to clarify, have you set up web address for the webhook and placed your code within index.php file in that folder(your server )?

Comment: It may be also possible that the certificate is not among trusted ones list for Telegram (If I remind right, they use the list in Debian Lenny)

Comment: Do you think it still could be a certificate problem? See my comment below: I used two different (official/3rd party) certificates to no avail. Tried both on PHP 5.6 and PHP 7. Any ideas for a solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you use selfsigned ssl you have to point to the ssl path ,,
use the ssh to run this command after filling it with your real data ,,

```
curl -F "url=https://example.com/myscript.php" -F "certificate=@/etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt" https://api.telegram.org/bot<SECRETTOKEN>/setWebhook
```

Comment: I have the same problem on two seperate domains. One with GlobalSign and one with Let's Encrypt. Could this still be the problem? I see many people struggling with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

After change to WebHook method, you need to put as follows, since now we are going to handle one message at time. For me works perfectly.

instead

```
$chatId = $updateArray["result"][0]["message"]["chat"]["id"];
```

to

```
$chatID = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
```

Comment: Actually this may be true, but it's the step prior to this that's causing the problem: 
$update remains empty when you use the webhook combined with `$update = file_get_contents('php://input');`

Answer (score 1):

this is the answer for all of your problems. 
follow this step after you got a secret token for your bot:

1. create file in your website https://yourdomain.com/secret-folder/index.php

create your php file like this :

```
<?php

    $website = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot123456789:1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF123/';
    $content = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $update = json_decode($content, true);

    if (isset($update["message"])){

        $chatID = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
        $text = $update["message"]["text"];

        if ( $text == '/start' ) {
            // send welcome message
            file_get_contents($website."sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=Welcome to my bot");
        }else{
            // send another message or do your logic (up to you)
            file_get_contents($website."sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=some text here");
        }
    }

?>
```

1. Set Your Webhook from this bot [@set_webhookbot](https://t.me/set_webhookbot)
2. choose command or type ' ست وب هوک '
3. reply with your secret bot token ex: ' 123456789:1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF123 '
4. reply with your webhook address 'https://yourdomain.com/secret-folder/index.php'
5. reply with /setwebhook

if you follow step by step its will work.

enjoy it !!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for digging up this old question so enthusiastically, I had exactly the same question as you.

I think actually the answer may be easier yet less satisfying as we hoped: I don't think it's possible to get a list of previous messages to the bot while using the webhook.
Namely: what this does, is run the PHP script directly as soon as the bot receives a message. Nothing is stored in an accessible database, hence no updateArray is returned.

I came across [this example](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples/hellobot), which shows how php://input works. I guess the solution to display a list of messages would be, let the php script store the message in a database everytime a message is 'forwarded' via the webhook.

If anyone found something else: I'm very interested.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding from your code snippet above, you need to use php://input within double quotes instead of single quotes. In php, we are having bing difference in this use case.